# javascript modulu execution is not clear

Tags: javascript

I have some code where it is written:

```
A = 'F'
if (A % 70 == 0) ...
```

Inspecting this with a debugger, I'm getting that the condition returns false.
'F' is ascii value of 70. So where is the issue?

Regards

Comment: Because `'F'.charCodeAt(0)` will give you the value of 70

Comment: What is the value of A as it written like that?

Comment: @AlonEitan I would assume because `'F' % 70` is `NaN`... or so my dev tools tell me anyway.

Comment: @Siguza, yes, I'm getting it as a NaN

Answer (score 3):

To get the unicode value use the charCodeAt method

```js
let A = 'F'
if (A.charCodeAt() % 70 == 0){
    console.log('yes')
}
```